# R Shiny CSS: Maintain text relative position upon zoom in/ screen size reduction

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to keep each number within its respective `knobInput`, regardless of zoom status or screen size. However, after zooming 120% or reducing the screen size, the number pops outside of its relative position.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(2, uiOutput("example_1")),
  column(2, uiOutput("example_2")),
  column(2,  uiOutput("example_3")),
         column(2, uiOutput("example_4")),
         column(2, uiOutput("example_5")),
         column(2, uiOutput("example_6"))
       )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example_1 =  output$example_2 =  output$example_3 = output$example_4 =  output$example_5 =  output$example_6 = renderUI(knobInput(
    inputId = "example_knob",
    label = NULL,
    value = 10,
    fontSize = "2em"
  ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Grateful for any advice as to how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

So ... The problem here is that you are not filling the horizontal space of your `fluidrow` which is 12 with your columns. Setting the columnwidth to 4 makes it work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(4, uiOutput("example_1")),
  column(4, uiOutput("example_2")),
  column(4,  uiOutput("example_3"))
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$example_1 =  output$example_2 =  output$example_3 = renderUI(knobInput(
    inputId = "example_knob",
    label = NULL,
    value = 10,
    fontSize = "2em"
  ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Julian_Hn. This works well for 3 inputs. However, upon completing 6 columns, the problem is re-introduced (please see my edited reprex). Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Graham Okay ... I think I've found the actual problem ... Am I correct that you only viewed your app in the `RStudio` display? If so: Please click on "Open in Browser" and check if everything is fine there. This might just be a bug with the RStudio display

Comment: I've been opening it on both Chrome and Safari - never in RStudio itself. Initially, the numbers are appropriately placed. Upon screen resizing or zooming in they pop out away from their respective knobInput. Thanks

Comment: Very Interesting ... I'm a Firefox User and cannot reproduce in Firefox. Everything scales fine there. But I just tried Chrome and the error occurs there as well.  So I'm a bit out of guesses as well here unfortunately